# How to mock ExampleMatchers by Example in java Using Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, mockito, query-by-example

Here is the example data:

```
 public List<Test> findByExample(Test bean) {
            ExampleMatcher matcher = DefaultExampleMatcher.exampleMatcher();
            Example<FiledReport> exampleQuery = Example.of(bean, matcher);
            return testRepo.findAll(exampleQuery);
        }
```

suggest best way to mock??